# Calculate the given sum

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Problem: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2}$$

This is a problem from a course of Fourier Series and the only hint was to use partial fraction decomposition.

I'm sure that this is meant to be solved by using Plancherel's formula: 
$$ \| f\|_2^2= \sum{k \in \mathbb{Z} } |g_n|^2 = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n^2 + b_n^2)$$
where $g_n$ is the n-th coefficient in an exponential fourier series of a function $f\in L^2([0,1])$, $g_n = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dx$, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are standard coefficients in a trigonometric Fourier series  of a function $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi]$).

Comment: How about finding the partial fractions??

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2} = \frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{2}{k+1}+\frac{1
   }{(k+1)^2}-\frac{2}{k}$.

Comment: That's a good idea. Summing $1/k^2$ and $1/(k+1)^2$ leads to $\pi^2/3-1$, and the other two terms cancel in a telescope way to yield $-2$. Final answer should be $\pi^2/3-3$, then.

Comment: If you have $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos kx}{k(k+1)}$ then you have $\frac{1}{2\pi}\|f\|_2^2$ is your sum.  I'm not sure what you can say about $f(x)$ though, and Hans' answer is far more elegant and direct, and uses partial fractions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, we have $$\frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2}=\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}+\frac{2}{k+1}-\frac{2}{k}.$$
Now, a standard sum is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}=\pi^2/6$$
so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty1/(k+1)^2=\pi^2/6-1$ so both these sums add up to $\pi^2/3-1$. The remaining part is
$$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=2(1/2-1+1/3-1/2+1/4-1/3+1/5-1/4+1/6-1/5+\ldots)=2\cdot-1=-2$$
so the final answer is $$\pi^2/3-3.$$

Comment: Since we sum only positive numbers, this proves that $\pi>3$.

Comment: This reminds me of an integral which equals $\frac{22}{7} - \pi.$

Answer (score 3):

Problem: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(k+1)^2}-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1-2=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-3$$